# UIButton crashes on uitouch event

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uitouch

I have a UIButton which sends the draginside event to:

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
```

It does this through the following code in viewDidLoad:

```
[colourButton1 addTarget:self action:@selector(touchesBegan:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

Within the method it sends it to, there is the following line:

```
UITouch *myTouch = [touches anyObject];
```

And for some reason, when dragging inside the UIButton this crashes the app. Any ideas why?

EDIT: The solution..

```
-(IBAction)buttonDragged:(id)button withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    NSSet *touches = [event touchesForView:colourButton1];
    [self touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're adding target to control you can pass 3 types of selectors for action -

```
- (void)action
- (void)action:(id)sender
- (void)action:(id)sender withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
```

Names don't matter, it's number of parameter which is important. If control sends it's target a message with 2 params then first parameter will be control itself (instance of `UIButton` in your case), second one - instance of `UIEvent`. But you expects instance of `NSSet` as first parameter and send it a message `anyObject` which `UIButton` doesn't understand. This is the cause of crash.

Why are you trying to send event from UI control to touch handling method `touchesMoved:withEvent:` in the first place? It will probably do something different from what you meant.

**UPDATE:**

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *t = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [t locationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(touchLocation));
}


- (IBAction)buttongDragged:(id)button withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    NSSet *touches = [event touchesForView:button];
    [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

Notice that since `touchesMoved:withEvent:` is a `UIResponder`'s method and controller's view *is* `UIResponder` this method will be also called on touch events for this view.

Comment: Because I want the user to be able to drag the button elsewhere. I've edited more code in above.

Comment: I see. I don't know if it's the best way to implement such behavior but if you absolutely need this you can get touches from event - `NSSet *touches = [event touchesForView:sender]`

Comment: Well, you can make a method like '- (IBAction)buttonDragged:(id)button withEvent:(UIEvent*)event`, add target to button with this it as action, retrieve touch events in it with code from above comment and call `touchesMoved:withEvent:` directly with this touches.

Comment: Hmm, i'm still not understanding this. Can you edit an example into your answer above?

Comment: It's ok, i solved it. I'll edit your answer into my question for future reference for people. Thanks so much.